# Finding out the size of a continuous aggregate

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, timescaledb, continuous-aggregates

Have hypertable table with a couple million rows. I'm able to select the size of this just fine using the following:

`SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('towns') );`

I also have a continuous aggregate for that hypertable:

```
WITH (timescaledb.continuous, timescaledb.materialized_only=true) AS
SELECT time_bucket(INTERVAL '1 minute', timestamp) AS bucket,
 /* random query */
FROM towns
GROUP BY bucket, town
WITH NO DATA;
```

I've refreshed the view and the data is showing as expected. However, I cannot seem to figure out how much space this new view is taking up.

`SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('towns_income') );` returns 0 bytes which I know isn't correct. I thought that maybe the total_relation_size for `towns` would increase, but that also seems the same. Am I missing something? I've tried `hypertable_size` as well with no success as mv isn't technically a hypertable.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/postgres-check-disk-space-taken-by-materialized-view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following SQL can help :)

```sql
 SELECT view_name, hypertable_size(format('%I.%I', materialization_hypertable_schema , materialization_hypertable_name )::regclass)
  FROM timescaledb_information.continuous_aggregates;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be the following SQL query

```sql
SELECT pg_size_pretty(SUM(total_bytes)), aggs.view_name  
FROM "_timescaledb_internal".hypertable_chunk_local_size hcls, timescaledb_information.continuous_aggregates aggs
WHERE hcls.table_name = aggs.materialization_hypertable_name
GROUP BY aggs.view_name;
```